# Обработка исключений try/except python

Tags: python, исключения

Не могу понять почему при обработке данного исключения выводится еще и None? 
[image: except/try python]

Comment: Не вставляйте скриншоты кода, лучше копируйте текст непосредственно в сообщение. Так и вам проще, и тем, кто отвечает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что исключение ты обработал, а из функции ничего не вернул. Это ничего и досталось `print`у, который его честно вывел.

Answer (score 2):

При выполнении кода у вас срабатывает исключение. В обработчике исключения есть `print`, он выводит `ii`. После выхода из функции срабатывает другой `print`, который должен вывести на печать то, что вернула функция `frtcher`. Но так как при срабатывании исключения функция она ничего не возвращает (в ветке `except` и ниже по коду функции нет `return`), то второй `print` выводит `None`.